# Steps to do in-app purchase for additional apps on the google market

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have seen the google dev links for in-app purchases. What I am unsure of is if you can have an in-app purchase to download an additional app that is related to the current one... in my case, I have a debt calculator app, but I want to have a link to my other debt related app....

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use in-app billing to purchase another app.

You can, however, send your users to a specific app in the Play Store by launching an Intent like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

You can also link to a list of all of your application by using the URI `market://search?q=pub:<publisher_name>`.